# Need help understanding why this function returns null

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am writing a Delphi Android app to use Google Push.

Here is the function in question. It always returns null:

```pascal
var
  PushService: TPushService;
  Notifications: TArray<TPushServiceNotification>;
  ServiceConnection: TPushServiceConnection;
begin
  PushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.Gcm);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('PushService');
  if not assigned(PushService) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('PushService error')
  else begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('PushService ok');
    PushService.AppProps[TPushService.TAppPropNames.GCMAppID] := '543546532983';
    ServiceConnection := TPushServiceConnection.Create(PushService);
```

Comment: Try to specify which function is returning null or append the whole function.

Comment: Use `FCM` instead of `GCM`

Comment: Helps to specify which Delphi version. It changed between 10.3.x and 10.4 (see Tom's comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TPushService.TServiceNames.Gcm` (Google cloud messaging) is deprecated, as that service is no longer provided by Google. You need to use `TPushService.TServiceNames.FCM` (Firebase cloud messaging) instead.

See [Firebase Android Support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Firebase_Android_Support) in Embarcadero's documentation for details on how to register, configure, and use FCM in your app.